# HTML5 Canvas - Add image on mouse click, at mouse coordinates

Tags: html, canvas

Alright guys, I have been trying to get this for hours now, I cannot find anything.

Can someone type up a quick script, or point me in the direction of a tutorial for this..

I want to have an image (imgObj) come up on the canvas when the user clicks on the canvas. I want the image to come up at the coordinates that the mouse is at when the user clicks.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could start here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

This is a tutorial on the HTML5 Canvas.

KineticJS is a library that makes this really easy: http://www.kineticjs.com/

essentially with KineticJS you can use the following methods to achieve your goal:

```
container.on("mousedown", function(){
      image.show();
 });

container.on("dragmove", function(){
     var mousePos = container.getMousePosition();
     var x = mousePos.x;
     var y = mousePos.y;
     image.move( x, y )
});

container.on("dragend"), function(){
     image.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use external libraries - just substitute the rectangle for your image by changing `fillRect()` to [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) accordingly:

```
var cn = document.getElementById("main");
var c  = cn.getContext("2d");
var mouse = {x:0, y:0};

window.addEventListener('mousedown', mHandler);

function mHandler(event) {
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
};

function main() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, cn.width, cn.height);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fillRect(mouse.x, mouse.y, 50, 50);
}

setInterval(main, 1000 / 60);
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96s20d7m/) of working example)

It sets `x` and `y` to to the canvas click location, then draws with [`fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect).

Note that this won't always work as expected because `pageX` and `pageY` change based on borders, padding, margins, etc. You can see this in the Fiddle. To make this work, simply change `pageX`/`pageY` to `offsetX`/`offsetY`, or use a polyfill.

Something like this in the `mHandler` function will work better:

```
if(event.offsetX && event.offsetY) {
    mouse.x = event.offsetX;
    mouse.y = event.offsetY;
}
else {
    mouse.x = event.layerX;
    mouse.y = event.layerY;
}
```

Or to shorten it up:

```
mouse.x = event.offsetX ? event.offsetX : event.layerX;
mouse.y = event.offsetY ? event.offsetY : event.layerY;
```

And then you can call:

`context.drawImage(imgObj, mouse.x, mouse.y, imgObj.width, imgObj.height);`

If you want the picture in the center of the mouse click, just call:

```
context.drawImage(
    imgObj, 
    mouse.x - imgObj.width / 2, 
    mouse.y - imgObj.height / 2, 
    imgObj.width, imgObj.height
);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/96s20d7m/4/) fiddle.